# blockUI error "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, blockui, ajax.beginform

I'm running this from within VS2010 and an error comes up when the form is submitted which says "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method".  Any suggestions?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function BlockUI() {
    $.blockUI({ message: "<h1>Remote call in progress...</h1>" });
}
</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Switch", new AjaxOptions()  {
        UpdateTargetId = "Switch" + Model.Id, 
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        OnSuccess = "",
        OnBegin = "BlockUI()",
        OnComplete = "",
        OnFailure = "alert('Failed to update switch')",
        Confirm = "",
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        LoadingElementId = "",
        Url = ""
    }))
```

Comment: Have both jQuery and the BlockUI library been loaded by the time this is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change

```
OnBegin = "BlockUI()",
```

to

```
OnBegin = "BlockUI"
```

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onbegin.aspx) `OnBegin` takes:

> The name of the JavaScript function to
>   call before the page is updated.

The additional `()` probably makes the underlying  JavaScript execute the function immediately, causing the error.

Similarly, with `OnFailure`:

```
OnFailure = "function() { alert('Failed to update switch'); }",
```

Also, you don't need to specify property values of `AjaxOptions` that you aren't using:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Switch", new AjaxOptions()  {
        UpdateTargetId = "Switch" + Model.Id, 
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        OnBegin = "BlockUI",
        OnFailure = "function() { alert('Failed to update switch'); }",
        HttpMethod = "POST"
    }))
```

Comment: @rob: Do you have jQuery referenced in a `script` tag in your view? If so, is it loading correctly?

Comment: <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-blockUI.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I have this on the _layout.cshtml in a default project

Comment: I can't say I'm much of an expert , so I'm sure it's something I've done incorrectly.

Comment: @rob: I've updated my answer. You can remove values for the `AjaxOptions` properties you aren't using and you should probably fix the `OnFailure` callback as well.

Comment: I had jquery-blockUI and it should have been jquery.blockUI with the period, Thanks!